# Multi user Saving Query in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, save

I am working on VS 2010 C# and SQL Server 2014.

My entry program generate new transaction number at saving and that number store in tables, I have `header` and `detail` concept in tables, meaning that in `header` table this data is stored:

- party Name/Code,
- Transaction No
- Date

and in the `details` table, these piece of information are stored:

- Item Code/Name
- Unit
- Rate
- Quantity

In the `header` table, I have an incremented column i.e. `SrNo` as integer.
On saving, 1st save in `header` table then get the max `SrNo` from header table and then that store in the `detail` table.

This is working fine on a single user/machine, but when on multi user / machines when save at the same time, data store on different `SrNo` in *detail* table.

How can I store entry when multi user save same program at the same time?

Comment: How you are getting id from heading table?

Comment: why not using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` ?

Comment: How you are getting id from heading table? 1st Insert in Header table then write query to get and store in variable of Max value of SrNo from Header Table. This variable use in Insert query of Detail table.